# Как использовать ActionFilterAttribute для проверки доступности действия?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

В [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) проекте для проверки доступности того или иного метода в gui я использую *фильтры действия*, пример такого *фильтра* ниже:

```
public class DisallowChangingTheApprovedOperationsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public IOperationService _operationService { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var valueResult = filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("operationId");
        if (valueResult == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valueResult.AttemptedValue))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("OperationId is not be null");
        }
        int operationId = int.Parse(valueResult.AttemptedValue);

        var result = _operationService.IsPublished(operationId);
        if (result)
        {
            if (string.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestType, "Get", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery);
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
                    new RouteValueDictionary { { "operationId", operationId } });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

его предназначение не допустить изменение утвержденной *Operation*, методя для переданного параметра `operationId` проверяет состояние `var result = _operationService.IsPublished(operationId);` и если результат `true` то происходит *отмена действия*

Данный *фильтр* я применяю к необходимым мне методам: `EditOperation`, `DeleteOperation` и т.п., пример метода для редактирования ниже:

```
[DisallowChangingTheApprovedOperations]
public ActionResult EditOperation(int operationId)
{
    ViewBag.Products = new SelectList(_productService.GetProductList(), "Id", "Name");
    ViewBag.Equipments = new SelectList(_equipmentService.GetEquipmentList(), "Id", "SelectListName");
    ViewBag.Units = new SelectList(_unitService.GetAll(), "Id", "FullName");
    var model = _operationService.GetOperation(operationId);
    return View("EditOperation", model);
}

[HttpPost]
[DisallowChangingTheApprovedOperations]
public Actionresult EditOperation(int operationId, EditedOperation model)
{
}
```

Для того что бы данный метод работал мне приходится в каждый из методов *таскать* `operationId` что мне кажется не удобным/не правильным, но это еще не все.

Так же у меня есть сущность `Program` которая относится к `Operation` в соотношении 1 операция много программ, для работы с `Program` у меня есть методы: `AddProgram`, `EditProgram` и т.п. Мне необходимо запретить изменения операции на основании её состояния(`_operationService.isPublished(int operationId)`) - нельзя добавить, изменить существующие программы, для этих целей я в методы редактирования, изменения, удаления программы передаю параметр `operationId` и применяю к методу тот же фильтр `DisallowChangingTheApprovedOperations`

пример метода для редактирования программы:

```
[DisallowChangingTheApprovedOperations]
//здесь прочие методы
public ActionResult EditProgram(int operationId, programId)
{}
```

т.е. здесь я помимо `id` программы мне приходися передавать еще и `id` операции, как вариант можно реализовать метод от наследованный от `ActionFilterAttribute` который на основании `programId` будет получать состояние *операции* и в соответствии с некой логикой отменять или разрешать действие, т.е. что то типа

```
public class DisallowChangingTheApprovedOperationsForTheProgrammAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    //получаем programId из контекста
    var result = _operationService.GetOperationStateForTheProgramm(programId);
    //отменяем действия в соответствии с логикой
}
```

Подскажите как поступить лучше/реализовать правильней возможность ограничения некоторых действий пользователя в соответствии с *некой* логикой?

Comment: как клиент узнает какой opertionId слать? Если это служебный параметр, его не обязательно добавлять как параметр роута, можно просто брать его из реквеста в actionfilter

Comment: @Grundy в представлении я формирую хелпером *ссылку* на метод с необходимыми параметрами

Comment: этот operationId используется как-то внутри методов? или только в фильтре?

Comment: @Grundy добавил в вопрос реализацию `get` метода `EditOperation`, а в методы изменения программ я его передаю только для *фильтра*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы подошли к задаче не с той стороны. Прежде всего, ваш подход (вводить дополнительный параметр просто чтобы его валидировать) попросту опасен - что если хакер передаст не тот номер операции?

Подумайте вот над чем. Отмечая атрибутом действия (Action), в которых нельзя менять опубликованные операции, вы архитектурно вводите существование действий, в которых менять опубликованные операции *можно* (к примеру, если вы забыли указать ваш атрибут).

Проверку разрешенности действия лучше бы спрятать в более низком слое, чем слой контроллеров веб-приложения. Если у вас есть слой бизнес-логики - то именно там наиболее логичное место для подобных проверок. Если же слоя бизнес-логики нет либо он есть но плохо спроектирован и разросся - то такие правила имеет смысл включить в слой DAL.

Так, если в качестве DAL вы используете EF, это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
class Context : DbContext
{
    protected override bool ShouldValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry)
    {
        // По умолчанию удаленные сущности не валидируются - но нам-то надо!
        return entityEntry.State != EntityState.Unchanged;
    }

    protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items)
    {
        if (entityEntry.Entity is Operation && entityEntry.State != EntityState.Added && IsPublishedOperation(entityEntry.Cast<Operation>()))
        {
            return new DbEntityValidationResult(entityEntry, new[] { new DbValidationError(null, "Cannot change published operation") });
        }

        if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
        {
            // Нам все еще не надо применять обычные правила валидации к удаленным записям
            return new DbEntityValidationResult(entityEntry, new DbValidationError[0]);
        }

        return base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items);
    }
}
```

Теперь на уровне веб-приложения останется правильно обработать ошибку валидации. Вот это можно уже сделать в фильтре.

PS аккуратнее с реализацией проверки `IsPublishedOperation` - надо проверять не текущее состояние операции, а исходное - в противном случае операцию будет невозможно опубликовать.

А для того, чтобы "опознать" в фильтре кастомную причину ошибки - вы можете создать наследника `DbValidationError`, благо он не запечатан.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42036/room-for-bald-and-pavel-mayorov